# Динамическое изменение style

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите,пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

Пытаюсь javascript'ом изменить цвет ячейки таблицы, а она мигает один раз нужным цветом и ничего не происходит. :)

Вот код:

```
<script>
function setTargetDay(obj)//запоминаем ячейку, по которой кликнули
{
    window.targetDay=obj.id;
}
function setColor(color)//меняем style.backgroundColor нужной ячейки
{
    if(!window.targetDay) return;
    var day=document.getElementById(window.targetDay);
    day.style.backgroundColor=color;
}

</script>

<table>
<tr><td onclick="setTargetDay(this);" id="monday">yo</td></tr>
<tr><td onclick="setTargetDay(this);" id="tuesday">yo</td></tr>
<tr><td onclick="setTargetDay(this);" id="wednesday">yo</td></tr>
<tr><td onclick="setTargetDay(this);" id="thursday">yo</td></tr>
</table>
<a href="" onclick="setColor('red');">red</a><a href="" onclick="setColor('green');">green</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При `href=""` происходит перегрузка страницы.
Нужно поставить `href="#"`.

Comment: спасиииибо))))ток я добавлю лучше return false в обработчик)действительно тупонул)